# String Split Ignore Last delimiter if no data

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I am string splitting some values that are comma delimited into rows.
However some values have an extra comma on the end.

**Example**

```
Userid |   Value
1      |   A,B,C,D,
2      |   F,H
```

**Code**

```
select value
from string_split('A,B,C,D,',',')
```

**Current Output**

```
UserId |   Value
1      |   A
1      |   B
1      |   C
1      |   D
1      |
```

Is there any way to make the string split function ignore the final comma if no data follows it?

**Desired Output**

```
UserId |   Value
1      |   A
1      |   B
1      |   C
1      |   D
```

Using MSSQL

Comment: Just add `WHERE value <> ''`?

Comment: That also removes NULL values, which i wasn't looking for. I have since changed my approach and will be removing nulls in the table, so your solution works.

Comment: `That also removes NULL values`. What do you mean by that ? `string_split` value column will not have null value. And If you pass a `NULL` value to `string_split`, it will not return any rows.

Comment: The view that i apply my String_Split function to had Null values due to the base table having nulls. These null values are not due to the split.

Comment: So your strings could look like "A,B,,,E,F," and in this instance you'd only want to remove the last blank? If so, maybe just do a check whether `RIGHT(Value, 1) = ','` and use a substring of the value, otherwise use the full string.

Comment: Don't forget: var split = String.Split("1,2,3", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: You'd stop having issues like this if you stopped storing multiple values in strings in the first place. SQL Server has types *designed* for holding multiple values. Ignoring them and choosing to use strings (especially with T-SQL's poor string formatting support) seems a little odd.

Comment: `''` isn't `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STRING_SPLIT Function doesn't support for lower version of sql server so first create a function to split the given string and join the function with your select query.Here is below sample for your expected result.
Created User defined Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Udf_StringSplit]
(
@Userid INT,
@Value VARCHAR(1000)

)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(
    Userid INT,
    Value VARCHAR(10)
) 
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
Userid INT,
Value VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @Data(Userid,Value)
SELECT @Userid, @Value

INSERT INTO @Result(Userid,Value)
SELECT Userid,
      Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS Value
FROM
(
SELECT Userid,
        CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(@Value,',','</S><S>')+'</S>'   AS XML) Value
FROM @Data
) AS A
CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
WHERE Userid=@Userid AND Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') <>''  
RETURN
END
GO
```

Sample data table

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE(Userid INT ,  Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 1,'A,B,C,D,' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'F,H'
```

Sql script to get the expected result

```
SELECT  d.Userid,
        f.Value
FROM  @Data d 
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Udf_StringSplit] (d.Userid,d.Value) AS f
WHERE d.Userid=1
GO
```

Result

```
Userid  Value
------------
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add "WHERE" sentence like this:

```
select value
from string_split('A,B,C,D,',',')
WHERE value <> ''
```